# android-release-unsigned.apk not up to date as android-debug.apk

Tags: ionic-framework

While making apk for my ionic app, the signed apk was not updated as the debug apk.
Means the contents in my debug apk(made from `ionic cordova run android`) are those which I want but the contents in my signed apk(made from `ionic cordova build --release android`) are the old ones.
Please help me its really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to mismatch of SHA key as while signing the we get a SHA key which is updated on firebase.
But after uploading it to play store we get a different SHA key so we must also add this SHA key to our firebase.